How do I query for all cells in a column that contain an exact text, even if the cell also contains more text than what I'm querying for?
I've got a sheet with a column of cells that all contain unique text, but they are all different combinations of pre-determined phrases. So, in a new tab, I'd like to pull all the cells in column E that contain the phrase "/Engages With or Creates Sensitive Content" for example.
This is the formula I've tried already: =TRANSPOSE(QUERY(Taxo!A:K, "SELECT * WHERE Col5 = '/Engages With or Creates Sensitive Content' ", -1 ))
But that only pulls cells that ONLY contain that text. I want all cells in col 5 that contain that text anywhere within the cell.

look up query CONTAINS parameter

Thank you! I just had to replace the = sign with "contains" and that did the trick. So simple. Thanks again!

You can use REGEXMATCH function, here are the details,
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en
